# htaccess rewrite subfolder to root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my root folder I have an `.htaccess` file that redirects URLs to a subfolder as follows. This folder contains a coming soon page:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?myotherurl.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ test [L]
```

When this rule is applied I get the following url: `http://myotherurl.com/test/`

Now I would like to rewrite (not redirect) the shown URL to `http://myotherurl.com` by creating a nested `.htaccess`. What should this file contain?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myotherurl.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ test/$1 [L]
```

This puts everything to the target directory. In your condition you missed to mask the dot. This does not matter in this case but it would also match the domain wwwamyotheeurl.com

If you have just one static page you could also use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ test/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rekire. With your solution I still get myotherurl.com/test instead of myotherurl.com

Comment: Did you try my first, the second or both rules?